# How to build a very basic Guard example?

Tags: ruby, guard

My goal is to build a simple custom guard with [Guard](http://rubygems.org/gems/guard). The gem install and bundler install for my app went fine. My Guardfile contains:

```
notification :growl

guard 'eyeball' do
  watch %r{^app/(.*)}
  watch %r{^config/(.*)}
  watch %r{^lib/(.*)}
end
```

Ok, next, I need to tell Guard what to do when a match happens. But I don't know where to do that. (In this case, I want to watch my application for changes and run some arbitrary code. Assume that there isn't a [guard available for what I want](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/List-of-available-Guards). I want to learn how to do it myself.)

In true 'blunder and see what errors pop up next' style, when I run `guard` I get this error message:

```
ERROR: Could not load 'guard/eyeball' or find class Guard::Eyeball
ERROR: cannot load such file -- guard/eyeball
ERROR: Invalid Guardfile, original error is:
undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
ERROR: No guards found in Guardfile, please add at least one.
Guard uses Growl to send notifications.
Guard is now watching at '/Users/my-user-name/dev/my-project-name'
```

So, that gives me a hint that  I need to create a `guard/eyeball.rb` file. Maybe? But how was I supposed to know this from the documentation?

I've read (several times) the very detailed and useful [Guard README](https://github.com/guard/guard/blob/master/README.md) but haven't found a good simple example that shows someone how to do 'just the basics' of writing your own guard. Unexpectedly, RailsCasts didn't really answer my question either: see [RailsCast #264 Guard](http://railscasts.com/episodes/264-guard?view=asciicast).

Did I overlook something in the [Guard README](https://github.com/guard/guard/blob/master/README.md)? Can you help or point to a good example? Thanks!

Comment: It's probably best to look at the source for some of the available guards and learn from them.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I did look at an example for exactly that reason. Still, I wasn't sure where to put files if I didn't want to package them up as a gem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sweet! I just found a Wiki page on the Guard wiki titled [Create a guard](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Create-a-guard) that answers my questions. It was not mentioned in the README, so I had to dig for it.

Comment: Thanks to [a recent guard commit](https://github.com/guard/guard/commit/560515a2e1244da7bb21b08a86a8239a93c96669) the README has been updated with this info.

Comment: Thanks for putting all this effort into a self-post; appreciated